# Github and sublimetext tab spacing

Tags: github, sublimetext3

After upgrading to the new iOS and getting a ton of Java exceptions from WebStorm, I've switched to Sublimetext.  I've changed my tab settings to 2 spaces (I've tried toggling between both true/false for translate tabs to spaces.

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
```

This seems fine in the editor, however now on new files whenever I push to github, it's showing a full tab or 4 spaces.  For those that use GitHub/Sublime, any idea how to fix this so github recognizing the tab settings also?

Thank you!

EDIT:

It turns out the following settings in sublime will do as expected:

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"detect_indentation" : false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not something you can control. Github represents tabs as 4 spaces. The actual file still consist of tabs, so will appear correctly in your text editor (assuming it is configured to 2 spaces per tab).

Comment: You sure? I have files pre-sublime that display correct in github and default to 2 spaces.

Comment: If that were the case, I would think `translate_tabs_to_spaces` would resolve that, as it would be spaces as oppose to tabs, but in sublime this doesn't seem to be the case (which I've tried setting to true)

Comment: I've made an edit above that works as expected, now in github it's 2 spaces.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just to point out, you've changed from using hard tabs (`\t`) to spaces. So that aligns properly. I made the assumption you wanted hard tabs, since you set translate_tabs_to_spaces to false.